# Conditional geo-location based search of documents with aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, search, nosql

My document schema looks something like this:

```
{
  "store_id": 123,
  "franchise_id": 1,
  "name": "test",
  "location": "1.2,1.3"
}
```

My use case revolves around finding stores. A store can be part of a franchise or it can be independent (franchise_id = store_id). So there can be multiple different stores as part of a franchise and I am using *franchise_id* field to identify that the store belongs to a franchise.

While searching for store with its name and a user location, I want to de-duplicate results based on the franchise id.

Now given a location, its distance range and name of the store as input I want to find stores grouped by franchise_id such that either I get

1. documents that lie within the range

OR if no store is present within this range for that franchise_id

2. the store doc with the minimum distance from the specified location

I've tried out reading about aggregations but I am not able to figure this out. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: i was reading your post, can you please explain this part once again "I want to de-duplicate results based on the franchise id."

Comment: what you have tried so far can help understanding your problem better.Thanks

Comment: ok, i understood what you are trying to do here, why don't you remodel your data again, top hits though will accomplish what you are looking for but i doubt its performance, i would suggest something like a parent-child relationship between franchise_id and store document, again for store with no franchise_id, store id can serve the purpose, i will try to put things together for you based on this in answer

Comment: Basically since a `franchise` can have many `stores`, if a user is looking for a store my aim is to show him the ones in his range or the one closest to him. Since bigger `franchise` can have a lot of stores I wanted to get a way by which I can get the results of store documents grouped by `franchise`. So that when a user chooses a franchise, he can see the list of stores within his radius, or a single closest store which is not in his radius (as he searched for the name I have to show at least 1 if found).
I hope this provides more clarity to my use case

Comment: yeah i understood, you don't need top hits and as of now i can suggest you to can use parent-child topoplogy as this will also allow you to nurture/enrich franchise info as well in parent doc along with franchise id for future use cases, please go through these docs and please try to understand them.i may come in later to help you with more once you get them. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/parent-child-mapping.html and https://www.spacevatican.org/2012/6/3/fun-with-elasticsearch-s-children-and-nested-documents/. let me know. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can group/deduplicate  the stores by `franchise_id` using a `terms` aggregation and within that a `top hits`aggregation. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html

Comment: The issue is that even though I can group by `franchise_id`, I want to only include the stores within the `range` or if no such store is in `range` the one with the least distance in each aggregated bucket.

Comment: You have to do the Geo  filtering in the query context. The aggregations are applied within that set only.

Comment: I can find the documents within range in the query section but without aggregating first I won't be able to find out the documents which are closest but are not in range per `franchise_id`.


For e.g. `store_id` 12 and 13 have `franchise_id` 1. Both have names which user is searching for. But none of them are in his distance range. I just want one which is the closest in that scenario (results being grouped by `franchise_id`)

Comment: Why do you need to aggregate first? Why do you need to use the franchise_id already in the first step? You first need to collect all stores within a radius. Then deduplicate in case there are franchises. You can basically sort within the top hits by distance. And sort all the buckets by the shortest distance to a franchise.